# Как мне сделать проверку ввел ли пользователь число, а не текст

Tags: java, java-8

Как мне сделать проверку ввел ли пользователь число, а не текст ( код там где я ввожу degrees или вторая try/catch ) и пользователь должен вводить до тех пор пока не введет число.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numbers;
        int degrees;
        int exit ;
        System.out.print("Hello,");
        while (true){


            System.out.print(" write number  of type convert:   \n 1-Degrees Celsius To Fahrenheit \n 2-Degrees Fahrenheit To Celsius \n Number: ");

            try{
                numbers = cin.nextInt();
                while (true)
                    if(numbers != 1 | numbers != 2  ){

                        System.out.println("Write right number ( 1 or 2 )");
                        numbers = cin.nextInt();

                        if (numbers ==1 | numbers == 2){
                            break;
                        }

                    }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Please write number ,not text");
                numbers = cin.nextInt();

            }

            System.out.println("Write degrees: ");
            while (true){

                try{
                    degrees = cin.nextInt();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Please write number,not text");
                    degrees = cin.nextInt();


                }
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После нескольких ответов на ru.SO у меня выбработалось правило большого пальца:

> Никогда не используйте `nextInt` (`nextDouble`, или другие `next...`)
> в интерактивном вводе.

Считывайте строку целиком (`nextLine()`) и преобразуйте в к нужному типу (`Integer.parseInt`):

```
private static int readInt(Scanner s, String prompt) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String line = s.nextLine();
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(line);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: wrong integer");
        }
    }
}
```

Чем плох `nextInt`? Тем что в случае ошибки, весь ошибочный текст остаётся в сканере так как будто чтения не было вообще. Если вы ещё раз вызовете `nextInt`, он снова попытается прочитать тот же мусор. У вас есть эта ошибка: при вводе неверных градусов программа зациклится навсегда. Мусор в случае ошибки нужно убирать вызовом `next`.

Если пользователь введёт несколько целых на одной строке ввода, `nextInt` считает первое число и передаст управление дальше. Если дальше есть ещё ввод он будет работать с остатком строки. Для пользователя это выглядит как то, что программа печатает приглашения на ввод, не даёт ввести данные и продолжает работу. Или позже сообщает об ошибках там где никакого ввода не было.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте hasNextInt() в условие while