# Как проверить введенные с клавиатуры данные с помощью Java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

недавно познал класс Scanner, и возник вопрос. Пишу программу в которой юзер вводит с клавиатуры число в диапазоне от 1 до 100. При этом надо произвести проверки - введено ли целое число, и в верном ли диапазоне оно введено. Написал следующий код, но он работает некорректно. Если я ввожу число вне диапазона, почему-то сразу не выводится сообщение о неверном вводе, а повторно надо ввести цифру. И если после этого ввести цифру в верном диапазоне, то все равно продолжается ввод с клавиатуры.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int enter;

    System.out.println("Введите цифру от 1 до 100");

    while (!sc.hasNextInt() || sc.nextInt() > 100 || sc.nextInt() < 1){
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введены неверные данные, попробуйте еще");
    }

    enter = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println(enter);
```

Comment: Советую глянуть этот ответ по считываю данных из консоли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257413/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82/1257612#1257612

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что в while вы два раза использовали метод nextInt(), то есть вы два раза прочитали значения с консоли.
Мое решение вашей проблемы - break;

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double enter;

    System.out.println("Введите цифру от 1 до 100");

    while(true) {
        enter = sc.nextDouble();
        if(!(enter < 100 && enter > 0 && enter == (int)enter))
        System.out.println("Введены неверные данные, попробуйте еще");
        else break;
    }
    
    //for work
    int number = (int)enter;
    System.out.println(number);
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Если чуть подправить Ваш код и вывести в отдельный метод, вроде как все работает.

```
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
int keyValide = keyValidation(key);

private static int keyValidation(Scanner key) {
  int numberValidate;
  System.out.println("Введите целое число от 1 до 100");

  while (!key.hasNextInt() || (numberValidate = key.nextInt()) > 100 || numberValidate < 1) {
    key.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Введены неверные данные, попробуйте еще");
  }

  return numberValidate;
}
```

Еще счетчик попыток не помешал бы здесь.